# Как происходит сравнение ссылок у Integer?

Tags: java, int

Наткнулся на очень интересный пример:

```
Integer a1 = 127;
Integer a2 = 127;
Integer a3 = 128;
Integer a4 = 128;
System.out.println(a1 == a2); //true
System.out.println(a3 == a4); //false
```

Почему?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Данные от -128 до 127 находятся в кеше и, при инициализации таким способом, новый объект не создается.
Внутри `Integer` есть `private class IntegerCache`, там в javadoc можно почитать поподробнее.

Comment: От -128 до 127. Байтовый диапазон закеширован по умолчанию

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) данные от **-128** до **127** (включительно) кешируются для `Integer`, т.е. для этих значений будет возвращена одна и та же ссылка на объект, поэтому сравнение как `==` работало, т.к. оно для объектов проверяет не равенство значения, а равенство ссылок.

Если поискать, то можно найти [реализацию метода](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L829), который и выполняет то кеширование:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

В том же классе `Integer` можно найти реализацию внутреннего приватного класса [IntegerCache](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L780), в котором задаются границы кеширования.